# How can I understand the while, do...while and increment operators in following program?

Tags: c

I am here from a competitive exam on "c". I cant able find the answer for the following c program :

```
    int i=1;
    do
      while(i++>5);
    while(i++>4);
    while(i++>3);
```

The question is to find the final value of "i". I have find out that the output is "4" by using gcc. But, I can't understand the mechanism. Please explain me...

Comment: Well, if you bothered to step through the code in a debugger, you would see the behavior.

Comment: This exact question was posted on stack overflow within the past few days. Sorry, I don't have (and am too lazy to look for) the link.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows the less/no searching effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st conditions**

```
while(i++>5);
```

here i =1, it fails but increments it to 2.

**2nd condition**

```
while(i++>4);
```

again fails but increments i to 3

**3rd conditions**

```
while(i++>3);
```

again fails but increments i to 4

So, you end up with a 4

Answer (score 0):

The tests increment. The loop executes and enters the text, `while(i++>5);` evaluates false, but i becomes 2. `while(i++>4);` evaluates false, but i becomes 3. `while(i++>3);` evaluates false (because of post-incrementing), but i becomes 4.